# JetPack Compose maxkeppeler / sheets-compose-dialogs

Tags: datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
internal fun CalendarSample2(closeSelection: UseCaseState.() -> Unit) {

    val selectedDate = remember { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3)) }

    CalendarDialog(
        state = rememberUseCaseState(visible = true, true, onCloseRequest = closeSelection),
        config = CalendarConfig(
            yearSelection = true,
            style = CalendarStyle.WEEK,
        ),
        selection = CalendarSelection.Date(
            selectedDate = selectedDate.value
        ) { newDate ->
            selectedDate.value = newDate
        },
    )
}
```

I would expect when CalendarSample2 is called selectedDate can be hoisted to Parent calling it via `UseCaseState.() -> Unit.`

I think a Lambda { } would be executed, but I am unable to get a value back from the CalendarSample2.

```
CalendarSample2(closeSelection = )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(){






    val selectedDate = remember { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3)) }

    CalendarSample2(selectedDate  = selectedDate){ selectedDate  }
 
    val mydate = selectedDate.value
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    val formattedDate = mydate?.format(formatter)
    Text(text = "Formatted Date = $formattedDate")
}




@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
internal fun CalendarSample2(selectedDate:MutableState<LocalDate?>,closeSelection:UseCaseState.()->Unit) {



    CalendarDialog(
        state = rememberUseCaseState(visible = true, true,onCloseRequest = closeSelection),
        config = CalendarConfig(
            yearSelection = true,
            monthSelection = true,
            style = CalendarStyle.WEEK,
        ),
        selection = CalendarSelection.Date(selectedDate = selectedDate.value)
        { newDate -> selectedDate.value = newDate
        },
    )

}
```

// I got it working.. not sure if this the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the UseCaseState as the parameter in the lambda function

```
closeSelection: (UseCaseState) -> Unit
```

and while calling this function pass the state

```
 state = rememberUseCaseState(visible = true, true, onCloseRequest = closeSelection(UseCaseState.Close),
```

Using this you will be able to get the return value from lambda function.

Comment: Trying the suggestions your made the App can no longer Compile.